# Modify xml doc in derived interface

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

Lets say I've got the following scenario:

```
interface Foo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Some documentation.
    /// </summary>
    void Foo();
}

interface Foo0 : Foo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Some modified documentation
    /// </summary>
    void Foo();
}
```

How could I achieve a modified xml comment in the derived interface Foo0 with valid c# code? 
I mean there is no possibility to override the method. Are there any tips on how to achieve a custom xml comment for the method Foo() in the Foo0 interface.

Comment: What's the point for inheritance here? I'd better remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the comment, is more likely you need a different method in the interface, because you are changing the theoretical purpose of the method. Anyway I think it is not possible, you may have to create an abstract class and implement the interface to create an abstract method with a different comment:

```
abstract class Foo0:Foo
{

   /// <summary>
   /// Some modified documentation
   /// </summary>
   abstract void Foo();
}
```

Comment: Well. I really need to use an interface. So is there no way?